# How to create a public Discord server that anyone can join without an invite?

Tags: discord

I want to create a new Discord server which I would like to advertise locally with small signs or stickers on the street.

Is there any short server ID or some customization string that I can use so that anyone can easily join this server?

Sharing an invite like is not good enough, because the random string is too long at 10 random characters: https://discord.gg/XXXXXXXXXX

Instructions that I've seen so far say you have to enable the "Community" feature: https://fixingguides.com/make-discord-server-public/

However when I do that it clearly tells me that the server has to have 1000 people for it to be discoverable:

> Fewer than 1,000 users
>
> You server must have at least 1,000 members to be eligible

so that won't work for me as this is a new server I'm trying to create.

Is there any better way than to point a URL shortened to an invite link or QR codes? I'd really like to avoid both of those, as a search by memorable name would be easier for people to find my server.

- https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/b9zdt6/join_discord_server_from_id/
- https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023968311
- https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/6jouf8/how_do_i_make_my_server_public/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Discord Partners](https://discord.com/partners). According to the Discord docs, one of the perks of being a Discord partner is that partners could customize the invite link. Once you be a partner, follow the instructions of [Custom Invite Link](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001542132-Custom-Invite-Link).

If being a partenr is not something that you can do now or you are not interested, you might use an actual link (HTML / markdown) rather than a the invite link provided by Discord which actually is an URL or you might use an URL shortener service.

If you will be sending the invite link by a email message you use the insert link tool of your email editor, using a short but descritive text and the invite link as the link URL.

Another option is posting the link somewhere that is easily reached by the people that you want to invite. Nowadays a lot many options: event invites i.e. from Zoom Meeting, Google Calendar, etc. chat apps like WhatsApp, blogs, online documents, etc.

Resources

- [How do I invite friends to my server?](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/204155938-How-do-I-invite-friends-to-my-server-)
- [Invites 101](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/208866998-Invites-101)